# Put Google search inside Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-search

Is there a way to put a Google search widget inside a cell of a Google Sheets?

I want to avoid my users having to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> every time they search. Would be very cool to have a Google Docs App that could be installed via "custom extension" but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the Web Search Gadget:

- Enter a few search terms in your spreadsheet.
- Highlight the cells where you entered data in step 1.
- Go to Insert > Gadget.
- In the Add a Gadget window, scroll to Web Search and click the Add to your spreadsheet button.
- The gadget menu appears in your spreadsheet. In the 'Range' field, enter the cell names where you added data in step 1.
- In the 'Title' field, create a title for your chart.
- Click Apply. The chart appears in your spreadsheet.

Extracted from the [Google Docs Gadget list](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99488)

Comment: Nowadays this answer is obsolete. By one hand, the link currently redirects to table of contents of the Google Sheets help on the Google Editors Help Center, by the other, gadgets are no longer supported, nowadays the Google Sheets UI is extended by using Google Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2021, widgets are not supported. Nowadays the Google Sheets UI is extended by using Google Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons. For details see:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons

It's worthy to mention that Google Documents and Google Slides have a feature to suggest content for documents and presentations respectively. For details see:

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2481802 for documents
- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7130307 for presentations